# Extra arguments in call

Tags: arrays, swift, string, tuples

Simple question here. How do I make this work? I know I could do each separately but how I do it like this without getting that error.

```
var zero = (prob: 0.2, label: "Dog")
var one = (prob: 0.3, label: "Cat")
var two = (prob: 0.2, label: "Fish")
Etc

var stringArray = Array<String>()

Func transfer(label: String) -> Array<Any> {
stringArray.append(label)
return stringArray
```

}

```
transfer(label: zero.1, one.1, two.1...etc)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is called “[Variadic Parameters](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Functions.html#ID171)”. Add three points after your String parameter type. For Example

```
func transfer(labels: String...) -> [String] {
   return labels
}
// you can now call
transfer(labels: zero.1, one.1, two.1)
```

If all you want to do is wrapping strings in an array, then you are better of with the array literal

```
var labels = [zero.1, one.1, two.1]
```

You can also convert tuples into an array of strings like this

```
func transfer(tuples: (Double,String)...) -> [String] {
   return tuples.map {$0.1} // which is a shorthand for {tuple in tuple.1}
}
transfer(tuples: zero, one, two, three)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is because you are passing like the error says: "Extra arguments" to the `transfer(label:)` call, which as you defined, is only receiving one argument. Change it to this:

```
var zero = (prob: 0.2, label: "Dog")
var one = (prob: 0.3, label: "Cat")
var two = (prob: 0.2, label: "Fish")

var stringArray = [String]()

func transfer(label: String) -> [String] {
    stringArray.append(label)
    return stringArray
}

transfer(label: zero.1)
transfer(label: one.1)
transfer(label: two.1)
```

Also you can do this:

```
var zero = (prob: 0.2, label: "Dog")
var one = (prob: 0.3, label: "Cat")
var two = (prob: 0.2, label: "Fish")

var stringArray = [ zero.1, one.1, two.1 ]
```

It produces the same output.